# Microsoft PowerApps Excel incremental load

Tags: excel, powerapps, incremental-load

I'm very new to PowerApps and have some task of making the app which will involve incremental data load. Currently we have chosen Excel sheets as the data source. So the actual task was make the data to be read from one Excel file and written to another Excel file somehow keeping track of new records since the last load. I was searching online but didn't find any such scenario. So there is a question: is such scenario possible/reasonable at all using Excels? And if not what would you recommend as data management system for such purpose working with PowerApps platform? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm suprised no one is recommending a.... database for this? anyway, there is no magic to incremental load. You need to have something in the source that gives you a "high water mark", for example a "date modified" field or an incrementing key.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you migrate your data to SharePoint Online . It is going to work faster and safer.

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered by Rodolfo, SharePoint Online is a good option. Some other options can be OneDrive, and I believe the premium-based Dataverse.

Here is PowerApps MVP Shane Young explaining why not to use Excel as the data source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtmZM3tm2Zs

For connectors, I recommend looking into: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/

> "Excel Online (Business) connector lets you work with Excel files in document libraries supported by Microsoft Graph (OneDrive for Business, SharePoint Sites, and Office 365 Groups)."